# Searching for a different value in a dictionary using another value in python

Tags: python, windows

```
thisDic = { "FirstName": 'admin',"LastName": 'sean', "tel":'7700321546', "balance": 10000}

def getBalance(tel):
```

i am supposed to query the thisDic for balance where telephone = tel

Please help

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: You cannot search that dictionary to find a `"balance"` value against `"tel"` because that structure can only hold a single record

Comment: @roganjosh but i first check if the tel exists which returns true. And then i have to get the balance attached on that tel

Comment: Dictionary data structure support for key-value. So you can only use the dictionary for doing things with key-values. So you have to use other data structure for your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean you have several dictionaries with the structure of thisDic?

if so,

```
def getBalance(tel):
    if thisDic['tel'] == tel:
        return thisDic['balance']
    else:
        ...
```